# Type ambiguity of arithmetic expression when wrapped in a function

Tags: haskell

I am writing a simple function on the GHCi command line (7.8.3)

```
let roundBy b x = (round (x/b)) * b
```

When evaluated, it gives an error about ambiguity (error message at bottom).

However, if I substitute the values, the same expression can be evaluated fine.

```
Prelude> (round (3/10))*10
0
```

My question is:

Is there a way to make ghci behave the same when the expression is encapsulated in a function, in the above case?

P.S.
Error message (when evaluated as a function):

```
Prelude> roundBy 10 3

<interactive>:19:1:
    No instance for (Show a0) arising from a use of `print'
    The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Show Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      ...plus 23 others
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's tricky but the thing is that the two `10`s in `(round (3/10))*10` don't have to be the same type but of course the `b`s in `let roundBy b x = (round (x/b)) * b` have to be.

That`s why:

```
λ> :t (round (3/10))*10
(round (3/10))*10 :: Integral a => a
```

but

```
λ> :t roundBy 10 3
roundBy 10 3 :: (RealFrac a, Integral a) => a
```

and GHCi just *knows* how to default to `Integral a` but obviously does not for `RealFrac a, Integral a`

---

so to really behave the **same** you would need:

```
let roundBy b b' x = (round (x/b)) * b'
```

and indeed:

```
λ> roundBy 10 10 3
0
```

---

### how to fix it

I forgot to add how to fix the *problem* here - I think you really want this:

```
let roundBy b x = (round (x/fromIntegral b)) * b
```

with this you get:

```
λ> :t roundBy
roundBy :: (Integral a, Integral a1) => a -> a1 -> a
λ> roundBy 10 3
0
```

by the way: it's usually a good idea to give the indented types for your function ;) so we can help you better

### another way to do it

From the looks of it you can simplify this function a bit using `rem`:

```
λ> let roundBy b x = x - x `rem` b
λ> roundBy 10 3
0
λ> roundBy 10 13
10
```